# How to send email to groups in lotus domino server using PHP

Tags: php, email, lotus-domino

I have a code in PHP that sends emails to users and its working as expected. I need help in figuring out as how to send email to a group defined in lotus notes. So basically there is a group existing with some name as DEV TEAM and if I type this directly, PHP throws `501 Syntax error, parameters in command....`. So, is there a way to figure out as how to retrieve the email address format for this group or any other way to send emails.

I know with all you gurus here, I will get some solution definitely:).
Thanks for any help in advance.

Please let me know if I can provide any other details.

Code through which I am able to send emails to users but not to a group in lotus notes.

```
<?php
$to = "testuserto@domain.com";
$subject = "TEST EMAIL";
$message = "Hello! Its is test email.";
$from = "testuser@domain.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: You're going to have to show some code here in order for anyone to give you an informed answer.

Comment: @rhsatrhs - added the code that I am using to send emails. It works fine for users separated by commas but not for groups:(.

Comment: It looks like you are using ordinary SMTP for the mailing, not the Notes APIs.  So, I think the tag Lotus-Notes is probably wrong for this post and it should be Lotus-Domino. I.e., what you probably meant to say is that the recipient users are using Lotus Notes, the server is Lotus Domino, and your PHP program is connecting to the Domino server via SMTP -- and under these conditions email to individual users is working but email sent to a groups that is listed in the Domino Directory on the Domino server is failing.  Is that correct?

Comment: @rhsatrhs - thats absolutely very correct. I am sorry I put notes instead of domino.

Comment: That's okay. A few people actually do try to programmatically submit messages via the Notes client's OLE interfaces, so I just needed to be sure I understood.

Answer (score 1):

See my comment on your question.  If my assumptions are correct, then the administrator of your Domino server must check the following:

- DEV TEAM is a valid group in the Domino Directory, with type "Mail Only" or "Multi-Purpose".
- There is no readers field on the DEV TEAM group that would restrict anonymous users from sending to it.
- There are no mail rules or restrictions in the server's config document that prevent messages from being sent to the group.
- The Internet Address field in the DEV TEAM group document in the Domino Directory has been configured.  This should be a valid RFC-821 address, such as DEV_TEAM@yourDomain.com (This is probably optional, but it makes it easier to document the solution.)

Once you have confirmed the above configuration information, your code should use the value that was configured in Internet Address field of the DEV TEAM group in the Domino Directory.  (I.e., DEV_TEAM@yourDomain.com)

Comment: I don't see `Internet Address` field when I click to create a new group or try editing an existing one. Any thoughts? I tried after connecting to one of PDL servers.

Comment: What version of Domino is running on your server?  The Internet Address field has existed in the Group document for a long time, but I can't remember when it was introduced.  In the current 8.5 version of Domino, you can see it on the Basics tab of the Group document, just above the Members list.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that is has got very little to do with the fact that it's a Domino server. I assume the address(es) in $from or $to are malformed. See also http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21105288, concerning strict RFC821 format, where '<' and '>' are required. 
In any case, mail to "dev team@domain.com" won't work, the address is invalid.

Comment: @Bugger - I think `<>` are added by default in php in mailto function. The error log says `501 syntax error, parameters in command &quot;RCPT TO:&lt;DEV TEAM&gt;&quot; unrecognized` . I tried with `DEV TEAM@domainserver.com` as well but no luck:(.

Comment: You cannot have a space character in an RFC821 address.

Comment: This is why you need to know the mapping for a valid address.  It is either an explicit mapping in the Internet Address field in the Group document (which is the best practice), or it is an implicit mapping such as DEV.TEAM@yourdomain.com or DEV_TEAM@yourdomain.com.  I don't recall whether Domino allows configuration of what characters to interpret as spaces, but one of these will almost certainly work.